# Dependency injection fails when testing Angular Library

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I've created an Angular Library which contains a simple component and a service which does a HTTP call and gets the result which then gets consumed in the component.

All works find except the fact that the tests won't pass with an error with dependency injection:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]:
   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]:
   NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

For reference here is my code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class MyService {
  public apiUrl = "https://apiurl";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getSomeData(key: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(
      `${this.apiUrl}/${key}`,
      { responseType: "text" }
    );
  }
}
```

And the test:

```
describe('MyService', () => {
  let injector : TestBed;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
    });

    injector = getTestBed();

  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service = injector.get(MyService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My guess is that it's something to do with @angular-devkit, but I might be wrong. And yes I have tried all variations and even tried to inject the real http-client which didn't work either.

Comment: Shouldn't you also import the `HttpClientModule`? The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpClientTestingModule) says that the testing module only replaces the backend handler used by `HttpClient`, it says nothing about providing a complete implementation of it.

Comment: Can you put this code in a small github repo so we can investigate? I suspect it has something to do with different types of HttpClient but I might be wrong

Comment: HttpClientModule is also imported with no difference. Will create a blitz shortly

Comment: Any news regarding reproduction?

Comment: Thanks for following up, I am probably in a different timezone . Give me an hour or so, will tag you here once done

Comment: @yurzui I just pushed the code up [here](https://github.com/yashints/ngx-pass-strength)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at your repo and discovered that you were focusing on `ngx-pass-strength.service.spec.ts` file but forgot that you didn't import `HttpClientTestingModule` in test for your component.

[ngx-pass-strength.component.spec.ts](https://github.com/yashints/ngx-pass-strength/blob/a47d794cb741fc9d9cc2bbc9a082a24daf05e470/projects/ngx-pass-strength/src/lib/ngx-pass-strength.component.spec.ts#L10-L13)

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ NgxPassStrengthComponent ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientTestingModule  <== add this
  ],
})
.compileComponents();
```

Comment: I were just testing the service for now, was there anything wrong there?

Comment: You have two spec files: one for service and one for component. Spec for service is fine, but spec for component is broken because it creates NgxPassStrengthComponent that injects NgxPassStrengthService in constructor. It since you didn't import HttpClientTestingModule in spec for component you see `Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]:` So just import it for that test file too https://github.com/yashints/ngx-pass-strength/blob/a47d794cb741fc9d9cc2bbc9a082a24daf05e470/projects/ngx-pass-strength/src/lib/ngx-pass-strength.component.spec.ts#L10

Comment: Gotcha, that's probably a commit issue

Comment: Once I imported it I have all green tests when running ng test